# Clear data from work_dir from mesos agents

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

I have a spark cluster which is running with Mesos as the resource manager. When some spark jobs fail, the temporary data files inside work_dir in mesos agent nodes does not get deleted. Is there any configuration to automatically clear the data from mesos agents' work_dir

Answer (score 1):

> ### Sandbox lifecycle
>
> Sandbox files are scheduled for garbage collection when:
>
> - An executor is removed or terminated.
> - A framework is removed.
> - An executor is recovered unsuccessfully during agent recovery.
>
> **NOTE:** During agent recovery, all of the executor's runs, except for the
>   latest run, are scheduled for garbage collection as well.
>
> Garbage collection is scheduled based on the `--gc_delay` agent flag.  By
>   default, this is one week since the sandbox was last modified.
>   After the delay, the files are deleted.
>
> Additionally, according to the `--disk_watch_interval` agent flag, files
>   scheduled for garbage collection are pruned based on the available disk and
>   the `--gc_disk_headroom` agent flag.
>   See the formula here.

[From documentation](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/sandbox/#sandbox-lifecycle)

Comment: Thanks ! I think I was looking for exactly the same. So if I wanted to delete the sandbox files immediately during failed jobs (i.e, when executor is recovered unsuccessfully), is it enough to configure --gc_delay=0 (What exactly are the values to be configured)

Comment: Correct, Set `gc_disk_headroom` to `1.0` or `gc_delay` to `0.0` you might need to change `disk_watch_interval` to smaller value but this may cause increased usage. If you want to clean work_dir after task finish you should think about custom executor that will handle it.

Answer (score 0):

The main space in `work_dir` are actually files in executors/runs/latest: stdout & stderr.

If executors are permanent, then `gc_delay` would not work any more. Since executors won’t be terminated or removed. So we must use another way — container_logger. [Docs here](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/logging/).

Configuring two flags: `modules` and `container_logger`. Thus `stdout` and `stderr` will be automatically deleted when meeting the max file size which is 10M by default.